# Why is this insert into a schema attached collection invalid?

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

Let's say, we have this schema :

```
Schemas.MyCollection = new SimpleSchema({
    something: {
        type: Object
    }
});
```

I want to insert something into `MyCollection`. For example :

```
var myobj = {
    aaaaaa: 11111,
    bbbbbb: 22222
};
MyCollection.insert({something: myobj});
```

We end up with this :

```
{
    _id: "someId",
    something: {}
}
```

When I disable simple schema checking (collection2), everything works as one expected.

Simple-schema did not report an error (collection2) so why it is invalid?

Comment: Please avoid swear words.

Comment: You will say the same after some hours of wastefull work thanks to genial library ...

Comment: I don't care. Your question was full of useless fluff that made reading it painful. You are angry, we get it, but please stay professional around here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Seraph your schema is wrong

```
Schemas.MyCollection = new SimpleSchema({
    something: {
        type: Object
    },

    'something.aaaaa': {
      type: String
    }
});
```

and so on you have to write every property the object has or you can do `blackbox: true` if you don't want to validate the object:

```
something: {
  type: Object,
  blackbox: true
}
```

Also if it's server-side operation you can do `myCollection.insert(doc, {validate: false});`

just read the docs https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2 :)

Comment: I need the object as a Map, so blackbox: true looks like solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference to help you understand more:

> https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#blackbox